# Extending Liferay UserLocalServiceImpl in an Ext plugin

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

In my [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) 6.1.1 installation I have extended (note: not overridden) the `UserLocalServiceImpl` class in an Ext plugin to provide a more relaxed screen name validation. However, I have been unable to get Liferay to load the new class instead of the default `UserLocalServiceImpl` class.

As far as I can tell, the ["normal" way](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-portal-servi-4) to replace service classes is to use a hook plugin. Unfortunately, hook plugins cannot access the implementation classes. I would have to extend `UserLocalServiceWrapper` instead of `UserLocalServiceImpl`, which would be very cumbersome for this particular use.

Is there a way to get Liferay to use my modified service class from an Ext plugin? Alternatively, is there a way to allow a hook plugin access to the implementation classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the service class implementation from an Ext plugin using the following procedure:

- Create a new folder named `META-INF` under `docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src` in the Ext folder.
- Create a new file named `ext-spring.xml` under `docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src/META-INF`.
- Search the Liferay *source* distribution for the `portal-spring.xml` file. In Liferay 6.1.1 it can be found at `portal-impl/src/META-INF/portal-spring.xml`.
- Copy the content of `portal-spring.xml` to the `ext-spring.xml` file that was created earlier.
- Remove all bean entries from `ext-spring.xml`, except for those that correspond to classes that will be replaced/extended.
- For each remaining entry, change the `class` attribute to point to the replacement class.
- Re-deploy the Ext plugin and restart the Liferay application server.

Comment: I used ext plugin to change an LDAP class and tried deploying. It is not working. Can you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399917/ext-plugin-not-working-in-liferay-6-1-2-jboss7